# sql check for logical errors in 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, data-modeling

Assuming I have an `employee` table with 2 columns only:

- employee_id
- manager_id

All employees added to this table would have an accompanying `manager_id` that is actually an `employee_id` that already exists (save for one, the CEO probably doesn't have a manager, but that's not important).

If `A` is the manager of `B`, how do we enforce a check such that A's manager can take any value BUT `B`, thus resulting in a violation of the business rule?

Comment: You want to check the condition during insert or impose restriction on the table itself??

Comment: Didn't you mix things up in the last paragraph?

Comment: Are you using MySQL, SQL Server, or Oracle? Or are you really looking for a coding solution for all three platforms?

Comment: Balanivash: check the condition during insert would be good enough

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: i'm using sql server 2008. a solution in any of these languages is fine. i just need to know how it's done at the db level.

Comment: @Jordão: thanks for the heads up. totally got the order wrong there. fixed it already.

Comment: Your requirement seems to allow A's manager to be any employee except those A manages. That sounds like a bad requirement. (A's manager could be the CEO's 16-year-old daughter who's working in the mail room until high school starts again.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the best way would be to create a TRIGGER on the insert into the table that would simply check that `manager_id NOT IN (SELECT employee_id from employee where manager_id = %insertid%)`.

Comment: _That_ trigger doesn't solve the issue. It only checks for _self-cycles_.

Comment: @Downvoter: If you downvote because you're expecting a fully functional answer, or retaliating to someone else's downvote -- maybe it's time to grow up?

Comment: i tried to upvote before accepting the answer but it's registered users only so... accepted answer it is.

Comment: ... and an ON INSERT trigger doesn't need to check for this. Since the employee is brand new, _any other employee_ can be his manager

Comment: -1 not because I'm expecting a fully functional answer, but at least an answer that points in the right direction...

Comment: @jordao: OP didn't ask for multiple levels of management, just one.  Also OP specified the problem was for values changed in the table, which would imply an ON UPDATE trigger.

Comment: @Paul, I think the OP wasn't aware of the _deeper_ problem with her "requirements". I just tried to give it a _broader_ interpretation, on something that would make sense for this scenario. What are the chances that you only want to check for _one level_ of management? Does that make sense as a requirement? Will the business be OK with "2 or more level loops are allowed"?

Comment: And although it implies an ON UPDATE trigger, you explicitly wrote "... create a TRIGGER __on the insert__ into the table ..." (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

The problem goes deeper than that, you want to avoid any *cycles* in your *graph*, making it effectively a *tree*.

I think you're better off doing that at the application level.

**UPDATE:** But if you prefer to do it with a trigger, take a look at [common table expressions (CTEs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163346.aspx). You can create a recursive query in a trigger that checks for cycles:

```
create trigger prevent_management_cycles on employee
instead of update
as

declare @found_rows int

;with cycle_detector (employee_id) as (
  select employee_id from inserted
  union all
  select employee.employee_id from employee
  join cycle_detector 
  on employee.manager_id = cycle_detector.employee_id
) 
select @found_rows = count(*)
from cycle_detector
join inserted 
on inserted.manager_id = cycle_detector.employee_id

if @found_rows > 0
  raiserror('cycle detected!', 1, 1)
else
  -- carry on original update
  update employee 
    set employee.manager_id = inserted.manager_id
    -- other columns...
  from employee 
  join inserted on employee.employee_id = inserted.employee_id
```

**Note**: it's assumed that `employee_id` is a primary key and `manager_id` is a foreign key pointing back to `employee.employee_id`.

Comment: A [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) would easily handle the issue.

Comment: Yes it would. But I normally prefer having this kind of _business_ logic separated from the persistence mechanism of the application. It's easier to maintain, test and evolve this way.

Comment: Database construction is based on business entities & their rules.  It's also centralized, just as easy to maintain, and scales loads better than all but the most simple applications.  Frankly, using a database as "dumb storage" is a complete waste...

Comment: So your application logic lives in stored procedures and triggers? Frankly, I've been there, and it didn't _scale_, development-wise that is.... Only for the simplest applications....

Comment: As few triggers as possible.  Otherwise -- tables and foreign keys primarily.  Operations by sprocs are my preference because ORM suffers on complex queries, and SQL in the application layer is more involved to test.  And forced parameterization...

Comment: Tables, foreign keys and operations (CRUD) still don't encapsulate the business rules of the application. Just its entities and essential relationships.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: care to share how you would construct the trigger in this case?

Comment: There's no difference between the logic being in a sproc (or trigger, constaints...) vs application code, outside of language.  Either approach is valid, depending the needs (database independence for the most part).  You grasp at straws...

Comment: @jaane: Paul Soneir beat me to the answer -- ask him for fully functional example.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: no he didn't. the problem here is not to reject the same value in both columns; that would be easy.

Comment: @jaane: There is no requirement for SO answers to provide a fully functional answer -- it's only in our best interest for upvotes. I believe you are capable yourself, but you could *ask* Paul to clarify...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: LOL guess i'm too noob for this site then. thanks for the replies. i loved the back n forth thing you had going with Jordão.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: it's one thing to say that a trigger solves the problem, which is _right_, but not the only way. It's a different thing to say that the _wrong_ trigger solves the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Half of the answer is a foreign key: manager_id references employee(employee_id)

The other half is a check constraint, manager_id<>employee_id

Comment: Oh, right, this won't ensure the tree thing. For that, especially if you intend to do operations on subhierarchies,look into the nested set model: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Comment: Check constraints won't be able to provide this -- trigger is the only option